# image floor fade color blend with background color of the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

How do I set the image overlay to match the background color of the webpage? [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjKxM.jpg).

Comment: this is not code, this is photo editing. You need photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background-blend-mode: overlay;`. See example below:

```css
.box {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjKxM.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #5e9bbf;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```